# Refactoring method with two outputs

Tags: java, groovy, functional-programming, refactoring

**Background**

I have encountered many methods in code I am tasked with refactoring that follow a general pattern as follows:

1. Take a composite input
2. Find children of composite according to some criterion
3. Remove children from composite, but keep track of them
4. Return the updated composite and append the removed children to an output parameter collection

In code it looks like this:

```
public Composite trim(Composite composite, List<Child> removed){

  for (Child child : composite.getChildren()){

    if (criterion(child)){
      composite.remove(child);
      removed.add(child);
    }
  }
}
```

There's a number of code smells here, but what I would like to address is how I can refactor this into immutable code that, accordingly, doesn't write to an output parameter.

**Possible, but not-so-elegant solution**

```
public Map<String, Object> trim(Composite composite){

  final List<Child> removableChildren = filter(composite);
  final Composite trimmed = copyCompositeWithoutChildren(composite, removableChildren);

  return wrapInMap(removableChildren, trimmed);
}
```

**Question**

Are there more succinct ways of doing this using, for instance, functional programming approaches like collect or splice in groovy or Java 8 that might inform a better, albeit more verbose, approach in Java pre-8? Examples from either of the languages would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

**2nd possible solution**

Inspired by [Steinar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23835222/2020801): Use strategy pattern.

```
public interface FilterStrategy {
  List<Child> filter(List<Child> children);
}

public interface RemovalResponseStrategy {
  void respond(List<Child> removedChildren);
}

public class CompositeTrimmer {

  private final FilterStrategy filterStrategy;
  private final RemovalResponseStrategy removalResponseStrategy;

  public Composite trim(final Composite composite){

    final List<Child> removableChildren = 
      filterStrategy.filter(composite.getChildren());

    final Composite trimmed = 
      copyCompositeWithoutChildren(composite, removableChildren);

    removalResponseStrategy.respond(removableChildren);  

    return trimmed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what kind of freedom you have to change the `Composite` class or which methods are
already available. So I just made something up. It can probably be refitted to what you have available
quite easily.

A little bit more groovy solution would be something like this:

```
def trim(Composite composite, Closure removeCriterion) {
    List<Child> removedChildren = composite.children.findAll(removeCriterion)
    List<Child> remainingChildren = composite.children - removedChildren
    Composite filteredComposite = new Composite(children: remainingChildren)
    [filteredComposite, removedChildren]
}
```

You don't need to specify the criterion as a parameter, but I kind of like it. Makes the code more
flexible.

So basically, first find children to remove, then create a new composite with the remaining children.
Finally return a list of both outputs. Since groovy supports multiple assignments from a list, that's
an easy way to return several outputs.

The solution was tested with a dummy implementation of `Composite` and `Child`.

Usage and test:

```
def test() {
    Composite composite = new Composite(children: [
            new Child(name: 'Angus'),
            new Child(name: 'Steinar'),
            new Child(name: 'Erik'),
            new Child(name: 'William'),
    ])

    def (Composite filteredComposite, List<Child> removedChildren) =
            trim(composite) {
                Child child -> child.name > 'H'
            }

    assert filteredComposite.children == [new Child(name: 'Angus'), new Child(name: 'Erik')]
    assert removedChildren == [new Child(name: 'Steinar'), new Child(name: 'William')]
}

@ToString(includePackage = false)
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Child {
    String name
}

@ToString(includePackage = false)
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Composite {
    List<Child> children
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The point about changing the composite class and injecting behaviours have changed my thinking about this problem. I will write another solution based on this rethink.